# Removing files from past git commits

Tags: git

I did a bad commit with a directory full of files (`/vendor/bundle/*`). After that I tried to fix it with changing `.gitignore`, so I did another 2 commits.

How can I remove `/vendor/bundle/*` directory from all the previous commits (without affecting any working files or other committed files)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an interactive rebase to remove the directory from your past commits:

```
# Go back 3 commits
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

You'll see your editor open with with list of commits:

```
pick <HEAD~2> Commit /vendor/bundle/*
pick <HEAD~1> OMG ignore /vendor/bundle/*!
pick <HEAD>   OMG ignore /vendor/bundle/* again!
```

Select the commit where you committed the directory and replace `pick` with `edit`:

```
edit <HEAD~2> Commit /vendor/bundle/*
pick <HEAD~1> OMG ignore /vendor/bundle/*!
pick <HEAD>   OMG ignore /vendor/bundle/* again!
```

The rebase will rewind to that commit and stop. Then do the following:

```
git rm -r -- /vendor/bundle
git commit --amend --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

You can read more about rewriting git history from the [FREE online Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html).